# How to use Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions?

Tags: c#, csproj

I try to use the Central Package Version from don't.

My `.csproj` looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions" Version="2.0.1" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My `Package.props` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Update="Newtonsoft.Json"          Version="12.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But that results in a warning with a false version of `Newtonsoft.Json`

[image: Solution Explorer]

```
Package 'Newtonsoft.Json 7.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. AppInsightsClient   C:\Users\peer.nissen\source\repos\AppInsightsClient\AppInsightsClient\AppInsightsClient.csproj  1
```

My file structure looks like that:

```
Solution
|-Package.props
|-Solution.sln
|-Project
   |-Project.csproj
```

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Just found [this](https://stu.dev/managing-package-versions-centrally/) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Packages.props should like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Update="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
<PackageReference Update="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And for you .csproj, it should like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<Sdk Name="Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions" Version="2.0.1" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <AssemblyName>HelloWorld</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>HelloWorld</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```